# Using Eigen on Mac OS X for XCode

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm triying to use Eigen on Xcode but I always get the "file not found" error. I installed Eigen using Homebrew, who puts it on

```
/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9
```

but when adding this path to the "Header Search Paths" I keep getting the "file not found" error. Is there any other way of using Eigen on Xcode?

EDIT: also tried with

```
/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9/include/eigen3
```

and I keep getting the "file not found" error.

Comment: In a terminal, does the file `/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9/Eigen/Dense` exist? If so, are you `#include <Eigen/Dense>` in your code?

Comment: The file exist in `/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9/include/eigen3` , you can find there `Eigen/Dense` , but I add that to the Search Path and nothing happens, writting `#include <Eigen/Dense>` gives me the "file not found" error

Comment: Now that is strange. In Xcode, are you sure `/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9/include/eigen3` is in the **Header Search Paths** for both the **Project** and the **Target**?

Comment: Also, do you have permissions to read that directory and all directories from `/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9` on down? That may be the problem.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't on both Project and Target, that fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, it only needs to be set for the **Target**. Setting it in the **Project**, all targets under the project should *inherit* this property, but I've noticed that sometimes this is not the case as Xcode changes from one version to the next, which is an evolving mystery for me.

Answer (score 1):

It probably should be

```
/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.9/include/eigen3
```

You need read the detailed error message and compare with the folder above to confirm the not-found file is there.